# Code for Reddit style image Carousel that's on home page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, carousel, reddit

[image]

Has anyone got any idea on how to implement this carousel into my website? I am using WordPress and I am not sure how to go about this. I was told to use 'foo gallery' to achieve the same look however, it doesn't really feel the same and also didn't work on my site (for some reason).

I have tried to code some of this but I am awful at coding and I am mainly just spending my time watching youtube help videos if I am being honest!

I'll explain my neeed for this and what I would like it to do and then, if you could help me that would be great!

So like on reddit, I would like to implement this feature on my home screen to show off some of the 'Hot topics of the day'. Preferably, some code could automatically update the images and text each day depending on the comments/views left on a page - so the top 4 most viewed pages would be automatically added to the front page with a custom image (which I have created). However, that seems quite hard. So just the layout/template of the images (like the photo provided) AND there is a way for me to manually change the images and names each day would suffice. I would also like to have 4 photos which also act as buttons with the curved boarders.(again, like the image I have attached)

Just so it's clear, I do not want these images to be able to move off like a slideshow, I just want them to stay in place and be able to change either manually or automatically.

Maybe this is called something other than a carousel and would be easy to do... i dont know! So if you do, please let me know.

Furthermore, I appreciate this is a place mainly for code to be posted however, I won't post my code as it is useless! If anyone wants to share any code or contact me privately then that would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Since you said you are awful in programming, why not use a plugin for WordPress? there's a very popular plugin where you can add a carousel easily.

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/

1. Install the plugin.
2. Create a carousel with the image you like. (Drag and drop)
3. Select the shortcode from the carousel you created from step 2 and paste it from the page you want it to appear.

Comment: ... or check the source code of the page, see how it's done, and replicate it on your project.